# Woocommerce: Display 'Downloaded' Marker on Products Logged-In User Has Already Downloaded

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce store with lots of different digital products across lots of different categories.  I also have an annual membership offer that allows members to pay one price and download anything they like from the store.  Because I have a lot of products, I'd like to add a little marker/badge/hover icon over any products they have previously downloaded, so they don't waste time/data/HD storage space downloading those products again.  I still want them to be able to re-download any of these products if they need to, so I still want them to show up in the store.  I'm using the Yith Membership plugin to handle the membership side of things, and Divi theme.

I'm OK with tinkering with a bit of code, and can edit bits and bobs using code snippets I find online, but I'm not knowledgeable enough with the language or the Woocommerce plugins to be able to figure out how to do this myself from scratch and haven't found any ways online, so could someone please suggest a way of achieving this please, and explain how as if I am 5 ;)

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your functions.php file but I would strongly suggest backing up before you make changes to the functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bbloomer_user_logged_in_product_already_bought', 30 );
  
function bbloomer_user_logged_in_product_already_bought() {
   global $product;
   if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return;
   if ( wc_customer_bought_product( '', get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id() ) ) {
      echo '<div>You purchased this in the past. Buy again?</div>';
   }
}
```

For reference this was taken from: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-check-current-user-already-purchased-product/

Comment: Thank you for responding. Perhaps I didn't explain properly what I'm trying to do; it's not 'purchased' items, but 'downloaded' items I want to flag, so members of a membership can easily see what items they haven't downloaded yet in a generated list of available products.

So the logic would go something like:
User logged in? Yes.  
User is a member of X membership? Yes. 
Loop through all products available to this membership. 
User has downloaded X product? Yes. 
Display checkmark icon over the item's product image.